# Make the database of synonymous tags visible to users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, automation

I see questions about if and how bad tags are automatically being corrected. They're popping all the time. Please make the database of synonymous tags visible to users to end these speculations once and forever. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to wait until synonyms are implemented: [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)

Answer (score 6):

Its done sir, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms yum waffles.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps when you enter a "bad" tag and click submit, it would alert you in some way?

Say you enter the `subversion` tag and click submit, it would say something like "Please use the `svn` tag instead of `subversion`"..

This would only happen the first time you click submit, so you could ignore it, should it be wrong.. It could also be done AJAX'ily, the same way the "Your question may be subjective" alert is done?

In addition, the tag-autocompletion should be made to suggest `svn` when you start typing `subversion`

The synonyms could be based of batch tag changes, say when `tagA` is merged into `tagB`, it stores the mapping in the synonyms database?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes. Do it please.