# Merge singular and plural tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I noticed there're tags that are actually the singular and plural forms of the same term, e.g. [string](/questions/tagged/string) and [strings](/questions/tagged/strings), and I guess most of them should be merged. Here're some possible candidates (tag counts are as of 7/17):

***Edit:*** grouped tags by count and sorted alphabetically.

**> 1000:**

- [array](/questions/tagged/array) (575) and [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) (878)
- [database](/questions/tagged/database) (3703) and [databases](/questions/tagged/databases) (14)
- [event](/questions/tagged/event) (158) and [events](/questions/tagged/events) (871)
- [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) (218) and [exceptions](/questions/tagged/exceptions) (864)
- [file](/questions/tagged/file) (601) and [files](/questions/tagged/files) (612)
- [generic](/questions/tagged/generic) (57) and [generics](/questions/tagged/generics) (1032)
- [image](/questions/tagged/image) (589) and [images](/questions/tagged/images) (539)
- [string](/questions/tagged/string) (1187) and [strings](/questions/tagged/strings) (277)

**500 - 1000:**

- [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) (610) and [browsers](/questions/tagged/browsers) (43)
- [class](/questions/tagged/class) (532) and [classes](/questions/tagged/classes) (151)
- [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) (639) and [compilers](/questions/tagged/compilers) (44)
- [function](/questions/tagged/function) (284) and [functions](/questions/tagged/functions) (316)
- [list](/questions/tagged/list) (476) and [lists](/questions/tagged/lists) (229)
- [pointer](/questions/tagged/pointer) (112) and [pointers](/questions/tagged/pointers) (400)
- [session](/questions/tagged/session) (557) and [sessions](/questions/tagged/sessions) (125)
- [table](/questions/tagged/table) (415) and [tables](/questions/tagged/tables) (128)
- [template](/questions/tagged/template) (217) and [templates](/questions/tagged/templates) (532)
- [tool](/questions/tagged/tool) (44) and [tools](/questions/tagged/tools) (919)

**100 - 500:**

- [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) (37) and [blogs](/questions/tagged/blogs) (111)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (45) and [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) (197)
- [build](/questions/tagged/build) (276) and [builds](/questions/tagged/builds) (15)
- [callback](/questions/tagged/callback) (27) and [callbacks](/questions/tagged/callbacks) (107)
- [certificate](/questions/tagged/certificate) (145) and [certificates](/questions/tagged/certificates) (33)
- [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) (152) and [checkboxes](/questions/tagged/checkboxes) (14)
- [connectionstring](/questions/tagged/connectionstring) (7), [connectionstrings](/questions/tagged/connectionstrings) (17) and [connection-string](/questions/tagged/connection-string) (95)
- [constant](/questions/tagged/constant) (24) and [constants](/questions/tagged/constants) (84)
- [constructor](/questions/tagged/constructor) (245) and [constructors](/questions/tagged/constructors) (25)
- [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie) (80) and [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) (359)
- [cursor](/questions/tagged/cursor) (52) and [cursors](/questions/tagged/cursors) (52)
- [dataset](/questions/tagged/dataset) (191) and [datasets](/questions/tagged/datasets) (91)
- [driver](/questions/tagged/driver) (84) and [drivers](/questions/tagged/drivers) (49)
- [entity](/questions/tagged/entity) (85) and [entities](/questions/tagged/entities) (23)
- [example](/questions/tagged/example) (30) and [examples](/questions/tagged/examples) (87)
- [field](/questions/tagged/field) (68) and [fields](/questions/tagged/fields) (50)
- [filesystem](/questions/tagged/filesystem) (78) and [filesystems](/questions/tagged/filesystems) (276)
- [folder](/questions/tagged/folder) (54) and [folders](/questions/tagged/folders) (72)
- [game](/questions/tagged/game) (85) and [games](/questions/tagged/games) (134)
- [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) (344) and [iframes](/questions/tagged/iframes) (10)
- [integer](/questions/tagged/integer) (132) and [integers](/questions/tagged/integers) (14)
- [interface](/questions/tagged/interface) (307) and [interfaces](/questions/tagged/interfaces) (171)
- [key](/questions/tagged/key) (53) and [keys](/questions/tagged/keys) (48)
- [language](/questions/tagged/language) (207) and [languages](/questions/tagged/languages) (48)
- [method](/questions/tagged/method) (109) and [methods](/questions/tagged/methods) (169)
- [model](/questions/tagged/model) (231) and [models](/questions/tagged/models) (25)
- [number](/questions/tagged/number) (61) and [numbers](/questions/tagged/numbers) (76)
- [object](/questions/tagged/object) (211) and [objects](/questions/tagged/objects) (176)
- [password](/questions/tagged/password) (106) and [passwords](/questions/tagged/passwords) (177)
- [path](/questions/tagged/path) (217) and [paths](/questions/tagged/paths) (42)
- [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) (67) and [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) (137)
- [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) (27) and [pipes](/questions/tagged/pipes) (87)
- [problem](/questions/tagged/problem) (97) and [problems](/questions/tagged/problems) (25)
- [process](/questions/tagged/process) (337) and [processes](/questions/tagged/processes) (150)
- [project](/questions/tagged/project) (78) and [projects](/questions/tagged/projects) (108)
- [property](/questions/tagged/property) (115) and [properties](/questions/tagged/properties) (300)
- [script](/questions/tagged/script) (256) and [scripts](/questions/tagged/scripts) (61)
- [service](/questions/tagged/service) (275) and [services](/questions/tagged/services) (126)
- [set](/questions/tagged/set) (45) and [sets](/questions/tagged/sets) (69)
- [stream](/questions/tagged/stream) (101) and [streams](/questions/tagged/streams) (120)
- [struct](/questions/tagged/struct) (156) and [structs](/questions/tagged/structs) (15)
- [style](/questions/tagged/style) (171) and [styles](/questions/tagged/styles) (77)
- [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) (62) and [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) (169)
- [temporary-tables](/questions/tagged/temporary-tables) (233) and [temporary-table](/questions/tagged/temporary-table) (18)
- [theme](/questions/tagged/theme) (34) and [themes](/questions/tagged/themes) (108)
- [timer](/questions/tagged/timer) (78) and [timers](/questions/tagged/timers) (110)
- [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp) (117) and [timestamps](/questions/tagged/timestamps) (8)
- [timezone](/questions/tagged/timezone) (161) and [timezones](/questions/tagged/timezones) (7)
- [trigger](/questions/tagged/trigger) (46) and [triggers](/questions/tagged/triggers) (213)
- [type](/questions/tagged/type) (99) and [types](/questions/tagged/types) (176)
- [update](/questions/tagged/update) (268) and [updates](/questions/tagged/updates) (19)
- [user](/questions/tagged/user) (112) and [users](/questions/tagged/users) (90)
- [variable](/questions/tagged/variable) (119) and [variables](/questions/tagged/variables) (307)
- [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) (186) and [vectors](/questions/tagged/vectors) (18)
- [video](/questions/tagged/video) (434) and [videos](/questions/tagged/videos) (19)
- [view](/questions/tagged/view) (132) and [views](/questions/tagged/views) (106)
- [widget](/questions/tagged/widget) (54) and [widgets](/questions/tagged/widgets) (86)

**< 100:**

- [alert](/questions/tagged/alert) (20) and [alerts](/questions/tagged/alerts) (24)
- [app](/questions/tagged/app) (34) and [apps](/questions/tagged/apps) (11)
- [border](/questions/tagged/border) (51) and [borders](/questions/tagged/borders) (10)
- [character](/questions/tagged/character) (44) and [characters](/questions/tagged/characters) (37)
- [container](/questions/tagged/container) (32) and [containers](/questions/tagged/containers) (56)
- [disk](/questions/tagged/disk) (35) and [disks](/questions/tagged/disks) (15)
- [expression](/questions/tagged/expression) (67) and [expressions](/questions/tagged/expressions) (21)
- [group](/questions/tagged/group) (41) and [groups](/questions/tagged/groups) (27)
- [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) (20) and [keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords) (63)
- [name](/questions/tagged/name) (56) and [names](/questions/tagged/names) (12)
- [feature](/questions/tagged/feature) (16) and [features](/questions/tagged/features) (63)
- [picture](/questions/tagged/picture) (21) and [pictures](/questions/tagged/pictures) (10)
- [sample](/questions/tagged/sample) (28) and [samples](/questions/tagged/samples) (19)
- [setter](/questions/tagged/setter) (11) and [setters](/questions/tagged/setters) (26)
- [shader](/questions/tagged/shader) (23) and [shaders](/questions/tagged/shaders) (13)
- [spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) (25) and [spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/spreadsheets) (35)
- [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip) (42) and [tooltips](/questions/tagged/tooltips) (52)
- [utility](/questions/tagged/utility) (19) and [utilities](/questions/tagged/utilities) (67)
- [value](/questions/tagged/value) (64) and [values](/questions/tagged/values) (19)
- [wildcard](/questions/tagged/wildcard) (33) and [wildcards](/questions/tagged/wildcards) (15)

Comment: Which would you prefer, singular, or plural?

Comment: Plural, definitely.

Comment: Let native speakers choose (I'm not one).

Comment: I was going down the list and lost it at vector/vectors. "What's my vector, Victor?" Classic. +1 just for that. Another +1 if I could give it for the good idea.

Comment: Common sense, please. Keywords should not be pluralised. Concepts probably should. And certain words need to be left alone because pluralising them would change the meaning.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the argument for pluralizing these?

Comment: @abatishchev See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags/135994#135994 for a more up-to-date list. Since such tag pairs can only be created by moderator intervention now, that list should be complete. And please update it if you clean up a pair.

Comment: @Gilles: Sure, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the [tag synonyms feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) was implemented, this can finally be easily handled by the community.

Although there seems to be no common/preferred form (e.g. [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) *sing.* but [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) *pl.*), I personally don't think it's much of the problem.

Answer (score 11):

This is a **tough call**. Tags that are clearly intended to be *keywords should be singular* (`foreach`, `static`, `array`, etc.)--`foreachs` makes no sense. However, *concepts should be plural* (`loops`, `types`, `arrays`, etc.). So, what do you do with tags like `array`? Some users are going to use the keyword `array` several times in a question, but really be asking about the concept `arrays`. Retagging this correctly would require reading and understanding the question. And you might get it wrong anyway. And you'd have to keep retagging.

What about conceptual tags like `looping`? Should be retagged as `loops`, right?

Maybe it's a matter of extending the tag matching logic to account for this. Ideally, there would be a way to indicate both. Entering `array/s` or `array$` or similar would match both (or all variants). If i want to monitor all looping questions, i should just mark `loop$` interesting and i get all questions marked `loop`, `looping`, `for-loop`, etc. Of course, i don't get `foreach` questions unless i mark `for$` as interesting too.

Bottom line is that it would be nice to clean things up, but that's problematic. **The real issue is matching tags.**

Answer (score 10):

Personally I'd favour the singular version over the plural generally speaking.

This might also be a good thing to factor out. Google for example is smart enough to realize plurals are equivalent to their singular form so there is no (or very little) difference between searching for "array" and "arrays".

We could pick a preferred one and make entering the plural form revert to the singular form (or vice versa if that's the consensus).

Answer (score 9):

These are going to need to be done on a case by case basis.  One reason why:

```
pipe = to send the output of one command as input to 
       another command. also, the vertical bar character.
pipes = Yahoo! Pipes
```

In some cases we could combine singular and plural versions into one tag like so:

```
group(s), value(s), type(s), etc.
```

Comment: +1 for the pipes example, but -1 for the "(s)" suggestion. so... net 0 from me. :)

Comment: Questions about Yahoo! Pipes should be tagged http://stackoverflow.com/tags/yahoo-pipes

Comment: I don't think most users of unix pipes etc will know to use the pipe tag rathern then the pipes tag.

Comment: If two very different phenomena are common in the programming sphere and differ by only an `s` at the end then that looks like a better disambiguation is needed.  Banning the "pipe/pipes" tag and having `unix-pipes` and `yahoo-pipes` would work better, because people would be prompted into thinking about which tag to use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say definitely go towards plural tags if this gets put into place.

Although, we'd want to be careful to make sure that the merging of plurality doesn't remove some important distinction.   For example, `generic` doesn't necessarily mean the same thing as `generics` (but it might in many cases).

Comment: What about something that is a keyword. e.g. string. strings is not the keyword, so would be incorrect.

Comment: @Colin Mackay: Maybe `string-keyword`? (By analogy with the `if-statement`, `switch-statement` etc.) There're already `like-keyword`, `params-keyword` and a few similar tags on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not possible to change them all in batch...
A more case by case analysis will have to be made I guess.

In the `Database - Databases` case for instance there are only 14 plural... so I think changing those to `Database` might make sense... Although 14 is not that much to take a look at them individually as well...

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea to merge them is good. I'm not entirely sure which way the community want it... any more feedback?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the tags should be declined/inflected so as to make the sentence “This is a question about ⟨*tag*⟩.” grammatically correct.

Comment: How could a singular/plural version make that statement grammatically incorrect? Could you give an example?

Comment: Going by that logic, they should all be pluralized: "This is a question about [strings, databases, tags, arrays]." *Edit: and the more I think about it, the more I think that putting the tag into this sentence is a great way to decide.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's one related retag request, `library` vs `libraries`:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12190/please-merge-the-libraries-and-library-tags

Please weigh in with your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more tags

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) & [discussions](/questions/tagged/discussions)

[best-practice](/questions/tagged/best-practice) & [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices)
and

[web-service](/questions/tagged/web-service) & [webservices](/questions/tagged/webservices)

Comment: best to post this as a separate question/retag request (tag it *retag-request* and *discussion* and the site name, eg, *stackoverflow* or *serverfault* or whatever).  it's more likely to be seen by those who can perform the retag.

Comment: I thought so, but i saw so many questions on re tagging. I will post separate question. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple Data Explorer queries that show most common tags with singular and plural version:

- [Tags with s-plural](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/111)
- [Tags with es-plural](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/112)

There are plenty of false alerts, but also plenty room for merging.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, as a rule of thumb, would be that if one is more than twice as common as the other, go with the more popular one (because that's the one people will be more likely to use when writing questions in the future).