# Rename [deleted-recent-posts] to [deleted-posts-page]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, retag-request

The tag [deleted-recent-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-recent-posts) was created for the pages that contained lists of a given user's deleted questions or answers, and which formerly constrained themselves to only those posts made in the previous 60 days, and subsequently those deleted in the previous 60 days.

However, the page [now contains all deleted posts of a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/377214) with no constraints, and the pages have been renamed "Deleted questions" and "Deleted answers".

The tags [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions), [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers), and [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts) all exist, but those tags are defined as being for deleted posts *themselves*, not about the page with those names.

As such, can the tag [deleted-recent-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-recent-posts) please be renamed (merged) to [deleted-posts-page](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts-page), as the page is now renamed (and its behavior changed)?

Answer (score 4):

♦ moderators can rename tags rather easily with the tag merge tool. It's as simple as entering the new tag name and submit the form:

[image]

and I've just done so. The new tag name is [deleted-posts-pages](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts-pages), so *plural*, because we're talking about two (slightly) different pages here.

Comment: The tag description for the current tag uses the singular form, so I thought that would be the preferred form. I have no problem with either form, as long as the wiki and excerpt are edited to conform to the plural form if that's chosen.

Comment: If somebody has a convincing argument for using the singular form, that's fine with me too. I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: Speaking of which, isn't tag renaming a single-step process, with the only thing needing to be done to merge the tag into the previously nonexistent new name? Or does that only work with tags with no wiki or excerpt?

Comment: Singular or plural? - Our migrated duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/3648282 and our local duplicates: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6752/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41501/282094 - choose the preferred form, where it's plural don't use singular (and vice versa), use synonyms to prefer the preferred form; see those links for additional guidance.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog I have no idea, but I can try (after I've saved the Markdowns of the excerpt & wiki, of course) ...

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog you were right, it was just a single step. I think they updated the process a year or two ago.