# Tag Synonym Request: [symbolic-references] <-> [symbolic-reference]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Currently there are:

- **2** questions tagged with [symbolic-references](/questions/tagged/symbolic-references)
- **4** questions tagged with [symbolic-reference](/questions/tagged/symbolic-reference)

I've checked the [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=synonym) page and it appears that this link hasn't been proposed yet.

**Note:** I had previously started to retag from singular form to plural form, then later reverted my changes as I'm not quite sure of which one should be the master. And it looks like nothing has been clearly decided on the [singular/plural front](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6752).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've retagged everything to [symbolic-references](/questions/tagged/symbolic-references) -- I've said my piece on singular vs plural tags many times, and in this case... it actually doesn't matter too much because the number of questions is so small. (I was actually surprised there were so few questions in those tags!) I'm not sure it's even worth adding a synonym, but of course, it couldn't hurt either.

Comment: Aside: I think the captcha threshold has been increased (!). I didn't get a single one doing the retagging.