# Have an automatic plausible tag synonym finder

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, automation

Here's an idea to make it easier to find tag synonyms: implement a tag synonym finder scheduled to run every X months.

**Note:** This process will *not* make any changes to tags, it will just display the results in a table accessible to everyone, and then be reviewed by humans to decide which ones are real synonyms.

It will take every tag, and then attempt to search its brothers and sisters:

- look for plurals: search for tags with an "s" on the end; for tags that end in "s" also look for those without one
- look for verbs: same as above, but with "ing"
- look for spaces: search for tags that are identical but without a "-" (this might be hard to do the reverse of)
- ...

<sub>But being careful to respect English grammar rules, for example, if we remove '**ing**' from [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging), we end up with '**flagg**' instead of [flag](/questions/tagged/flag). So it would be wise to both remove '**ing**' and '**(*)ing**'</sub>

I know it is a tedious and heavy task (for both machines and humans), but if done right, it can make things easier and cleaner.

Comment: slightly related:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags manual retag request of plurals