# Shouldn't the [ontologies] tag be a synonym of [ontology]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

While answering a semantic-web-related question, I noticed there is a tag [ontologies](/questions/tagged/ontologies) on StackOverflow that seems like a duplicate of [ontology](/questions/tagged/ontology). It has a strange, plural form, has no description and questions tagged with it match the other one very well.

I think it should be marked as a synonym or perhaps deleted (there aren't many questions tagged with it).

I don't have the ability to suggest a tag synonym, much less create one. Therefore, I thought I should write a question here so you, grown-ups can fix it.

Comment: And [shouldn't we have an automatic finder](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140918/have-an-automatic-plausible-tag-synonym-finder) for these easily-to-find synonyms applying basic grammar rules like your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There, [ontologies](/questions/tagged/ontologies) is dead. Long live the unicorns!

Comment: That was a fast kill. Thanks :)