# Tag Merge Request: [messages] and [message]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[messages](/questions/tagged/messages) x 352

[message](/questions/tagged/message) x 955

We should merge tag [message](/questions/tagged/message) into [messages](/questions/tagged/messages).

See [Merge singular and plural tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags)

**Edit:**
Current count is: 
[messages](/questions/tagged/messages) x 431
and
[message](/questions/tagged/message) x 1188

Is there any progress with this retag request?

As per [comment of  BoltClock's a Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142655/tag-merge-request-messages-and-message#comment441375_142655), shouldn't we burninate tags or just retag?

Comment: This tag is far too generic to keep around. This is what I'd consider a tag for burninating...