# Merge tags threads/threading/multithreading on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

[`threads`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threads) and [`threading`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threading) seem identical. [`multithreading`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) also seems very similar

`threads` is used 175 times, `threading` is used 84, `multithreading` is used 2679 times.

I would say threads and threading should be merged into multithreading?

I could only find 2 questions tagged with [`single-threaded`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-threaded), so I can't see a reason to have both threading and multithreading, but [this post by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/request-for-more-restraint-when-retagging/17121#17121) seems to disagree.

On a related note, there's also a bunch of threading-related tags that could be cleaned up a bit. I've done a bunch... but I'm not sure how to retag the question ["How does a non-forking web server work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912974/how-does-a-non-forking-web-server-work) - it's not using a single existing tag, which seems wrong, but I can't find any suitable replacements..

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

This could get messy on a global merge. Should be a case-by-case retag.

[Unless, of course, you're definitely sure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17051/request-for-more-restraint-when-retagging/17121#17121) that all instances of **`[threading]`** are also talking about **`[multi-threading]`** or vice versa.

Questions about threading are not all talking about multi-threading, and even questions about the latter are not talking about the former.

Comment: I could only about three questions using tags regarding single-threading, so I don't think there's any reason to have threading and multithreading be two separate tags.. Then again I'm not too sure, thus the question!