# What are the funniest Trilogy posts?

Tags: discussion, humor

I'm including Meta in Trilogy.
Is there a more accurate term? (Quadrilogy?)

Comment: Accurate in the sense that "octopodes" is the more accurate plural of "octopus", yes.  That is, not in any sense that people actually use.

Comment: I meant accurate in describing the sites.  (perhaps family)

Comment: Tetralogy - dilogy, trilogy, tetralogy, pentalogy, hexalogy, etc.

Comment: @Izzy: And the plural of "octopus?"

Comment: Your question now is worse than before. It's like you've only just started using SO. What's going on with the users of late?

Comment: Adam - no idea personally, but did dig this out (From Cambridge Guide to English Usage): *octopuses, octopi, octopodes. Currently, octopuses is the most common form in the US as well as the UK; octopodes is rare, and octopi is often objectionable.*

Comment: "Funniest" is the new "must have"? What the hell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hands down:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: +1... but it feels like beating a dead pony with a laser cooked waffle

Comment: er sorry, whose hand?

Comment: Do not use apostrophes to indicate plural. Because apostrophe does not indicate plural. Apostrophe cannot indicate plural. Not even a greengrocer can use it to indicate plural. Ule çòrrùpt thè Èñglïsh læñgüägé größl¡.

Comment: Oh... but there are always exceptions: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe

Comment: @beggs - that is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to nominate the [frantabulous explanation of tag usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions/31779#31779).

Comment: How can I not upvote this one? :)

Comment: By not clicking your mouse? Kidding... +1