# Should there be high-rep-user contributed descriptions for tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

Hello, I have seen [Tag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/tag-description) but I would like to bring new action to the topic as well as clarify some points of how it could work..

First of all, there are a lot of cryptic and ambiguous tags out there. For instance the `r` tag and the one here `always-friday-in-iceland` (which I have no idea about). Some of these may be difficult to google about but I propose a way so that high reputation users can contribute descriptions to tags that regular users will enjoy. (and prevent mis-tagging and questions here about what a certain tag is for)

I say high-rep (either access to mod-tools or able to edit posts) users should be able to click on a tag and it bring up a page for the tag. They can then click on a link like "provide description" or something like that to contribute a description. They can also vote on other contributed descriptions. I don't think reputation should be given for these votes. The one with the highest amount of votes gets displayed to all users. (possibly with a small link for "see other descriptions" on the tag page)

This of course will be subject to moderation to avoid inappropriate descriptions, but I believe this should be a good way of describing tags and giving relevant Wikipedia pages and/or official product pages

How does this sound to you guys? I'm sure it would require more than some trivial line of code for stack-exchange, but I think it'd be worth it so that we don't have confused users wondering what tags like `code-golf` mean.

Also, as an aside: This would be great at like the 5000 or 7000 rep mark as a stepping stone before the 10k mark :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we can have the tag description show on the tag stats page, like so:

[alt text http://img294.imageshack.us/img294/7323/tagdescription.png](http://img294.imageshack.us/img294/7323/tagdescription.png)

Comment: Yes, thats what I was intending, I mean that for if you want to contribute a new description you would click on some link.. sorry if my wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: @earlz, ok, I see, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @edit: Yes, that mockup picture is exactly what I'm intending for regular users to see.