# Display page with more background information about tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, information-display

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Tag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/tag-description)
>   [Create a tag homepage/FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq)
>   [Should there be high-rep-user contributed descriptions for tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41177/should-there-be-high-rep-user-contributed-descriptions-for-tags)

I saw a question tagged **[[plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plsql)]**. I have no idea what it is, but judging from what I saw in that specific question, I'd like to know more about it.

It would be nice if I could click on the tag and get a short description of the technology with links to more info. Sort of like the tag pages for sponsored tags have now.

Naturally this isn't very important, since it's easily Googled, but it would be a nice extra service. The info pages could be wiki as well (or probably must be for the idea to work).

Comment: This has been asked before.

Comment: here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/tag-description and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41177/should-there-be-high-rep-user-contributed-descriptions-for-tags

Comment: Or you could, I don't know, try find out about it yourself? http://www.google.com/search?q=plsql http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL

Answer (score 1):

Well, since tags can be created on the fly by just about anyone I think you'll find that the vast majority of tags will go unannotated.

However, I do see merit in doing something like this.

Each tag could have an editable description available to users with a certain amount of rep (I'd say 2000, since that's when retagging becomes available). Any user would be able to alter the description and it should keep an edit history, too.

Looking at it that way might cause some trouble, though, since so many users could edit tag descriptions at the same time. You'd probably want to have some kind of locking mechanism once a certain percentage of users agree that the description should be finalized to prevent overediting.

Possibly you'd also want something to re-open tag descriptions if enough people disagree with them. I don't know. It's a good enough idea, but it would be hard to maintain.

Comment: Retagging is available at 500; 2000 is "edit other people's posts"

Answer (score 0):

On the tag page we could display a wikipedia-like section that can be edited by 2k+ users, explaining what the tag means.

The FAQ says that the website is a mix of a wiki, blog, reddit and a forum.. I think the "wiki" part is really lacking; so I think implementing this would be a good idea.