# Reference to Policy "`not-` tags inappropriate on this site"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

A user has claimed that:

> `not-` tags are inappropriate on [StackOverflow].

Can anyone provide a reference to the policy/decision to which he refers?  Or is he just stating an opinion?

For example there is a tag I created, and he edited my question to remove it based on the above.  Under what circumstances do I have the right to rollback his edit if I disagree with the change?

**Background:** Almost any question asked in the Algorithm tag can seem like a homework question and many times randomly these questions receive a "Is this homework?" comment, almost always from someone that has never asked a question and never received a answer in the Algorithm tag, which is extremely annoying.  I guess I will simply continue to ignore this question.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11492811/revisions ? Adding a `not-homework` tag? (If so, editing out was absolutely the right thing to do and you should not re-create it. That's a worthless tag, could be applied to millions of questions without adding any value.)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: And further a `not-homework` tag would be useful for questions that look like homework but are not homework, to avoid the two comments "Is this homework?" from some script kiddie with primary tags `bash` and `php`, and then another comment "No this isn't homework".  It reduces noise.

Comment: WRT this doesn't answer your question: it indeed is a comment. Re: usefulness of "not-homework" tag: I disagree. It's about as useful as "not-working" or "question". It would be used by the wrong people for the wrong reason (i.e. seeing it would, in my opinion, in 95% of cases, indicate a homework question).

Comment: Whatever 95% wrong people that use it for the wrong reason can just as easily answer the question "Is this homework?" with the answer "No this isn't homework".  It raises the signal/noise ratio.

Comment: +1 Mat! I agree. The OP should just say in the original description that it is not for homework, then they won't need to add a silly tag in.

Answer (score 12):

Most `not-` tags would be meta-tags as classified by [Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

You can't tag a question with only a negative, you'd always need something more to define what "category"/"area" your question belongs to. ([homework](/questions/tagged/homework) is a meta-tag with a long history of debate attached to it.)

See: [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) – don't create meta-tags. Tags are there to classify, to help searching, to get tag-experts to look at your question. I can't see anyone following the [not-c++](/questions/tagged/not-c%2b%2b) or [not-jquery](/questions/tagged/not-jquery) tags.

If you are after an answer that doesn't use LibraryX or some specific feature from your language or framework, state that in your question (possibly with a reason why if that would have been the most logical thing to do/use). But negative tags aren't a good idea at all IMO.

Comment: There is the blog entry I was looking for!

Comment: I'd follow [tag:not-jQuery]! ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

### How can I write to the console in C#?

I would have added more tags, but there are only five allowed. :(

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [not-java](/questions/tagged/not-java) [not-winforms](/questions/tagged/not-winforms) [not-textbox](/questions/tagged/not-textbox) [not-homework](/questions/tagged/not-homework)

---

No, they're definitely not useful. Tags should describe what your question is about, not what it is not about, and especially not what your intentions are (or not). That the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag exists is a pure edge-case which should be reconsidered sometime.

Comment: not-any-other-tag-except-the-ones-included-except-the-ones-starting-with-not

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.  I asked for a reference to policy/discussion on this matter.  Not for an opinion about whether it should be policy.

Comment: @user1131467 - I don't think there is an explicit policy document other than the usual one on meta tags.

Comment: @user1131467: [Doesn't get more official then this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136889/can-we-put-a-moratorium-on-the-great-tag-cleanup-of-2012/138384#138384)

Answer (score 1):

Tags exist and are used to identify a question, allowing interested or expert users on the given subject to answer and provide some assistance.

If you prefix a tag like [not-xxxxx](/questions/tagged/not-xxxxx), it doesn't mean anything. Having the tag present or not is the same thing.

**e.g.,**

> How can I import a large CSV file?
>
> [php](/questions/tagged/php) [import](/questions/tagged/import) [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) [not-homework](/questions/tagged/not-homework)

This will immediately, as already mentioned by @Mat direct the user's thought to "This is homework"!

Others will just re-tag the question.

---

**From this community wiki:** [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/184576)

> Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer.

No one gets connected with [not-xxxxx](/questions/tagged/not-xxxxx).