# Burninate the [no-javascript] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I just spotted a tag called [no-javascript](/questions/tagged/no-javascript). The [wiki description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/no-javascript/info) makes it pretty brief:

> This tag is a signal that the answer to this question should NOT contain any javascript as a part of its solution.

This tag wiki is a signal that the tag should NOT [exist](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags).

Comment: ... Was there actually a need to post this question instead of just silently removing the tag?

Comment: @waiwai933: Considering that it has just received an answer from someone whose question contained the tag, yes.

Comment: And if you had not posted this question, would that user have noticed and complained on meta?

Comment: @waiwai933: The user has to be on meta to notice, so chances are he would have posted asking why the tag was removed anyway if I hadn't posted. You know how vocal people can be about getting their tags removed, so you could consider this a preemptive self-post.

Comment: You're running a strict tagging ship here guys. I can understand the reasoning behind describing content, but why wouldn't a NON tag be useful, especially when it's very good at filtering? Need more brain power to process?

Comment: Seems like you more-or-less unilaterally burninated a tag, and got +103 rep in the process?  It's good to be a moderator ...

Comment: @John: It's meta rep, so it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welp.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139913/reference-to-policy-not-tags-inappropriate-on-this-site

Comment: +1 for this cool graphic ...

Answer (score 0):

I actually like it because I don't like code to be run on my machine (or someone else's that has a slow one and the designer doesn't care because 16x multiple core processors is his standard).

Proposal: add to the wiki answer something like `This tag is a signal that code in question does NOT contain any javascript as a part of its architecture or that javascript can NOT be used for some reason (eg. very slow CPU, javascript not available, run when javascript disabled)`

### EDIT1:

**Questions to consider for meta tags**

1. does it add value? (not taking into account the proposed usage)
2. is the "damage" greater than the value?

### EDIT2:

#### Example of a 'too good' filtering meta-tag

**Consider this tags: [number] [not-odd]**

[number] question related to numbers - OK

[not-odd] question related to ?? maybe numbers, maybe straight, maybe - ??

[number] [not-odd] question related to numbers that are not odd => even numbers probably - OK

Comment: I don't think you understand what a "meta tag" is and why it's so frowned upon, nor have you clicked the link. Then again, my question was badly-written, so I'm going to rewrite it to make the link more prominent.

Comment: true, didn't see that link (contrast and lum on my LCD are bad) but I read the "related" and I think my answer threw some other kind of light on the problem. So even if the circumstances to use it as a single tag are slim, it could still define the content (with the ^ mentioned addition to the description) but intuitively probably

Comment: The thing is that "I'm looking for a solution that does not involve Javascript" *isn't a thing that should be a tag*.

Comment: What's the desired method of signaling that "I can't use JS" then?

Comment: @Charles: in the web today this would be a perfect example for a tag, not for a "category" but a tag (or a "meta-tag" if you want)

Comment: The way to say that you don't want a solution in Javascript is to not tag the question with any Javascript-related tags and mention in the question body that you don't want a JS solution... and give a reaason for it.  Like "this code needs to run in Lynx, so it can't be done using Javascript."

Comment: Interestingly, I intuitively searched for it while tagging the question and was glad. Second best option was to amend the text with something like that @Charles.

Comment: Yes, that is also the most natural way of saying it.