# Changing and editing tags on a question

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

For a new user, it might be hard to judge what an appropriate tag for a question is.

There should be a way for the public (and not just those with edit privileges) to change or add tags to a question. At least suggest appropriate tags.

Comment: There is. As part of suggested edits, you can suggest different tags. Can you explain why you think this doesn't exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31776/282094

Answer (score 1):

You can edit and only change the tags and this will place your suggestion in an edit queue that higher rep users will approve or disapprove your edit. You will also gain 2 rep for each approved edit.

There was once an edit and retag button but the retag was removed and instead retags are lumped in with the edits. When you hit 500 rep you can hit edit, change only the tags, and then it will bypass the review queue.

Comment: Though, chances are that if the tags need changing, there are other things in the post that can be improved - why not do that too?

Comment: @Oded 'tis a very good point!