# Merge [rails] into [ruby-on-rails]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

[[ruby-on-rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails): 16,358
[[rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails): 52

I've checked the questions, all the ones with [rails] talk about Ruby on Rails. (Appears to still apply to the new batch of [rails] questions.)

<s>Some are also tagged as [[rails] [ruby-on-rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+rails).</s> (Fixed.)

Could these please be merged into [ruby-on-rails]?

Comment: This probably doesn't need a discussion, so it might be better tagged with **[support]** instead of **[discussion]**

Comment: @brad: fixed. I never know how to tag on meta

Comment: [rails] is now a synonym for [ruby-on-rails], and has 40 renames in the past 23 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, moved all the Rails to Ruby-on-rails.

Comment: yay! thanks [char limit]

Answer (score 1):

I have completed this request by hand on an additional 33 questions.

Given the volume of questions in `[ruby-on-rails]`, this is bound to come up again and again. Normally I'd ask a mod to mark this question `[status-completed]`, but until [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) are implemented, I suggest leaving that off the question, so retaggers can come back and recheck this periodically.

**EDIT**: Now that tag synonyms are implemented, this is taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

People keep using [[rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails).  Some technological measure is needed unless we really want to retag it every month.

As of June 4:
  [[rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) x 63 (oldest is from May 26, just over a week ago)
  [[ruby-on-rails]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) x 14,416

Both have several questions asked today, and usage seems steady, just higher for the latter.