# Should there be an automatic retag feature?

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)

There are an unending series of "retag" requests. Should there be a feature that has a map of synonyms, so that for example if someone enters `XP` it is automatically rendered as `Windows-XP` (as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42493/retag-request-xp-windows-xp-on-super-user)) or `gmaps` -> `google-maps` (as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7524/retag-request-gmaps-google-maps))?

I suppose then it should also handle multi-word merges, as with `web` and `development` -> `web-development` (as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7118/retag-request-web-development-web-development)).

Comment: indeed great minds think alike..

Comment: Hmm. I looked for a similar question before posting, and failed. Perhaps we need synonyms for the words in questions about synonyms. ;)