# More specific tag suggestion when tagging new question

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am active in `asp.net-mvc` tag and I see that many people tag their question with `asp.net` and `mvc` tag, but not `asp.net-mvc`. Since `asp.net-mvc` is constructed by combining `asp.net` and `mvc`, I suggest showing a message like:

> Since you selected **asp.net** and **mvc** tags, maybe **asp.net-mvc** may be suitable too.

Message would show only if a combined tag has high popularity.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms/7484#7484 among others.

Comment: @John Saunders: That is not the same. My suggestion doesn't need to store any lists and is easier to implement.

Comment: I didn't mean that yours was a duplicate, only that it's in the same direction.

Comment: The tag synonym system is planned to be added, so asking to have something added to support the old system likely won't fly with the powers that be. Moreover, I just tried it, if you put in `asp.net` in the tags window and let the suggestions drop down, `asp.net-mvc` is the *second item* in the list under `asp.net`.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: It is second and still not selected in many cases. It is 8 months since synonym system was declared as planned and we'll have to propably wait a lot of time before it is implemented. Having big plans doesn't mean that we can't make little improvements.