# Merge tags [user-interface] [ui]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I don't really know which one should be preferred.

[[user-interface]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) (811)
[[ui]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui) (837)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good spot for [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) because the spellings are so different.

Without tag synonyms, I would favour going with `[ui]` because there is already `[gui]` (2658) in the system, with a huge number of questions, and there is no longhand variation of the tag. I think anyone who writes out 'user-interface' only to have it *not* show up as a registered tag will probably be able to figure out to retry the tag with 'ui'.

Honestly there really isn't a good solution to picking one or the other without the synonyms.

**EDIT:** Now that tag synonyms have been implemented, there is a synonym in the system mapping `[ui]` --> `[user-interface]`.

Answer (score 4):

I would *always* prefer the full version unless the initialism/abbreviation is *so thoroughly* ubiquitous that the original is rarely-to-never used (think IBM != International Business Machines).

This is a good candidate for tag synonyms.