# Why didn't this question go through close votes review?

Tags: support, bug, review, flags, vote-to-close

I flagged [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44503/349538) as off-topic, but my flag aged away. Since I'm not aware of Meta having the same [problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349542/4284627) with close votes as Stack Overflow, I was curious to see why my flag aged away, so I looked at the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/44503/timeline). To my surprise, the question never went through close vote review, although I flagged it as off-topic.

Why didn't this question go through close votes review? Is it because it's too old? Is it because it's tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)? If any of those are the case, why allow me to flag it if my flag won't have any effect? Is it a bug? Is there any other reason?

Why didn't this question go through review even though I flagged it?

Comment: why r u flagging questions from the stone age?

Comment: FYI in 2k10, meta se that is this site is the meta for all sites (per site metas introduced later). So when asked, it is clearly on topic

Comment: When did you flag this question?

Comment: @Glorfindel September 1st 2017.

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks. I can't remember having reviewed that question, but I don't see it in the list of reviews either (as a 10k user you can review *all* past reviews).

Comment: I can confirm the findings from @Glorfindel with the usage of [my review finder script (only for 10K-ers useful)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306412/578411), and as it was flagged before the last SEDE update, I checked ReviewTasks: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/721820, also empty

Comment: This happened again, this time with the Low Quality Posts review. I flagged [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58431/349538) as a link-only answer two months ago and my flag is still pending.