# Is it possible to add the ability to unify tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms)

I saw on several occasions usage of very similar tags, that are suppose to actually be same tag (math & mathematics for example).

Is it possible to add for those 10k rep users the ability to merge tags into one tag, and so save some verbosity.

Comment: No, it is not possible, but we desperately need such a system. Please show your support by upvoting the feature request I've linked to.