# Is [sql-server-management-stu] a stable tag for SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Which tag do you recommend to use for `SQL Server Management Studio`? I didn't find any good one - appropriate and often used.

Currently [[sql-server-management-stu]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-management-stu) (110)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50685/alternative-tags-for-tags-that-got-truncated -- in the meantime, I'm retagging this question as discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[ssms]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) (119) has a few more questions.

Also see [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ssms) questions.

Comment: +1, SSMS, or TEFKAQA, the executable formerly known as query analyzer

Comment: The problem with SSMS is that it is not going to show up when you start to type "sql-server-management-studio" or anything truncated combination.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to propose `[sql-server-mgmt-studio]` as an alternative.  It's not perfect, but at least it will show up on the list when people get as far as typing "sql-server-m" in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about `[sql-server-mgmt-studio]` from the other request I linked to, but no matter what until [synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) are implemented, the questions will *still* get fragmented between `[sql-server-xyz]` and `[ssmsxyz]`.

Honestly, I think it would be better to just leave `[sql-server-management-stu]` alone, because if someone decides to spell it out instead of stopping to look at the autocomplete, they won't find the proposed tag at all ('mgmt' is unsearchable).

IMO, the only thing we can consider doing is merging together `[sql-server-management-stu]` and `[ssms]`. I favour the former so everything is grouped together with `[sql-server-xyz]`, but they're both so evenly split, it's a tough call.

Sadly, I can't think of a good solution to this without [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms). :(