# How does the tag synonym suggestion feature work?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

You can now propose and vote for new [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=tag-synonyms&sort=info&pagesize=50).

Are synonyms with enough votes automatically promoted to a synonym, or are votes just suggestions to Mods that it's a good idea?

Some clarification on this new feature would be great.

Comment: wow, when did that get implemented? I completely missed this feature

Comment: And it's also on the new SE sites... coolness all around

Comment: @Juan, must have been late last night (Pacific time, or maybe early Australia time....)  Ask @waffles, he would prolly know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tooltip on the voting control says "total votes (when a synonym gets a score of 3 it is automatically approved)".

So it would appear to be completely automatic.

Since the threshold is so low, I'm curious if there is a reputation threshold for the vote itself. Waffles commented on my [tag synonyms system proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms/49872#49872) saying "status-completed" so I'm assuming there *is* a threshold, but probably lower than the 5k I proposed (since I also proposed a vote system with thresholds of +5/-5 instead of 3). Anyone with a test account want to take a peek?

**EDIT:** This is now more clear. A proposal is accepted at +4, and rejected at -2. You currently need 2k rep to be able to vote (either way).

Comment: I should have noticed that.  So, it really only takes 3 people to approve a new tag synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Every new feature on SO worked like this.

They are pushed live with no explanation, but a blog post quickly follows it explaining it in detail.

I guess it's their way of beta-testing things with low traffic (you need to find it yourself) and with no knowledge of how it works (tests usability)

Comment: `badge-request` for proposing synonyms in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: That's actually a good idea.  Creating synonyms is a behavior that the SE sites should want to encourage.  There should be a badge for it.

Comment: Check out the tag synonyms page on SO. Bill the Lizard is in line for a gold badge already (although he cheated...).

Comment: @mmy, yeah, if I could propose a tag and have it automatically be made a synonym that would be way too easy.

Comment: @Justin: Actually, he scraped the tag synonym question and generated a script to run all the INSERTs.

Comment: @mmy, that is definitely cheating.