# Tag Synonyms Should Allow Popular and Correct Names

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow tag synonyms where the source has more instances than the target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target)

Right now, "You may only suggest synonyms that have a question count lower than the tag selected."

That's unfortunate, because if a less-correct tag has even one more use than a more correct tag, you can't suggest it as a synonym.

For example, the correct name of WCF RIA Services is, well, WCF RIA Services. But "RIA Services" was the name used while it was in CTP (not officially shipping). I tried to propose `ria-services` (184 questions) as a synonym for `wcf-ria-services` (101 questions), and the system would not allow the proposal.

Possibly better rules:

- You could propose a synonym if the "better" tag had at least some % of the "not so great" tag.
- You can propose any tag as a synonym, and people vote on which of the group they think is the best tag.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target covers the general case of "Allow synonyms with higher instances". Not sure if yours is distinct enough to not be a duplicate.

Comment: @Grace, I think I'll make my proposal an answer to that question. This one could be marked as a dupe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can request here that a mod retag to the more appropriate tag.  Then propose the synonym after that has happened.

If the decision is made to change this behavior then so be it.  If not, well then see the above.