# The [Conditional-operator] tag should be the main synonym even though the [Ternary-operator] tag has more questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49012/how-could-we-fix-the-ternary-operator-problem), there are more references to the tag [ternary-operator](/questions/tagged/ternary-operator) than the more correct [conditional-operator](/questions/tagged/conditional-operator).

Given that there *are* very few other ternary operators it is probably fair enough to make it a synonym of [conditional-operator](/questions/tagged/conditional-operator), and according to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target) this needs to be a separate meta request. This is that request. (At the time I posted this question there was a [synonym suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=ternary-operator) in the other allowed direction.)

(Two years later I don't think this should happen. I just updated the tag formatting.)

Answer (score -3):

I know how excited everyone gets about this; every mention of "the ternary operator" immediately gets attacked by people who were apparently lying in wait for someone to utter that phrase, but if everyone calls it the ternary operator it probably makes more sense to leave it that way. The important part is that searching for "ternary operator" find the posts about it, and I don't think tag synonyms rewrite searches, so these rewrites make searching less effective. If they do handle searches then it doesn't really matter

Comment: Do the people searching for it even know its name at all, though? Seems like most questions dealing with it are "What's this ?: thing called?"

Comment: Tag synonyms will be worse than what we have now if they __don't__ handle searches!