# Worksheet-function tag synonym request

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I went and added a wiki for [worksheet-function](/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) and then tried to add the synonym [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula), but because there are more instances of [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula) it wouldn't allow it.

We should be using [worksheet-function](/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) because of other spreadsheet apps, instead of using the more specific [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula) (any tagging of this for Excel problems should use the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) tag also).

How do I get this synonym implemented?

EDIT: Ok, [worksheet-function](/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) now exceeds [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula) so I've created a synonym [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/worksheet-function/synonyms).  Please vote for it if you're able.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target -- if you'd like, you can edit this question into a retag/synonym request.

Comment: @Jon, ok, guess I'll have to, what a sucky way to implement things, makes the voting completely worthless

Comment: Did you read [waffles' answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target/58855#58855)? He actually had a pretty good reason why it's the way it is

Comment: @Mic, yes, but if we need to be careful we should be careful both ways, and let the voting decide.  See my [new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60415/we-need-one-place-to-see-and-vote-on-tag-synonyms) for my solution.