# We need more voting on ALL tag synonym requests

Tags: feature-request, voting, tag-synonyms

All tag synonym requests should be exposed more for voting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vote for Tag Synonyms Directly on the Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137922/vote-for-tag-synonyms-directly-on-the-page), though it might be that the OP wants even more visibility. There are more specific feature requests for that, e.g. notifications or a review queue.

Answer (score 4):

The [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) page shows all current and suggested synonyms. You can filter it to show [only suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested); the number in parentheses next to `pending` is how many votes it has

Comment: How do you get there from the main page, I can only get there through your link.

Comment: I found the complicated way, I'll mod this and add another feature-request.

Comment: @Lance: You can get there from the tag-info-pages, click on *"see all tag synonyms »"*.

Comment: It would also be helpful to have a filter to show only the current/suggested synonyms where I am eligible to vote. Currently, I have to look at my profile page and make a guess as to which tags have enough upvotes (after I've checked the FAQ to see what that minimum threshold even is). By the time I've done all that, my compile is finished and I'm back to work for another hour...

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind...

Moderators have a one click approve process. I will frequently go through the list and approve trivial things. This process is significantly more efficient that the old "retag-request" route on meta.

I am not totally against exposing this a bit better when we do the tag page refactor (in the next few weeks) but for now this will have to wait.

Comment: I don't have a problem waiting a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

We could have all proposed tag-synonyms auto-generate a question on Meta, that could then be seen and voted on.

Comment: that would cause a flood on meta

Comment: @waffles, I mean once the first waves have died down.