# Vote for Tag Synonyms Directly on the Page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

### Before:

[image: The current tag synonyms page]

### After:

[image: The proposed tag synonyms page.]

---

### The pros:

- Speeds up the tag synonym voting process.
- Easier to locate (as opposed to navigating to each individual tag wiki page).
- Encourages users to vote on more than one at a time.

### The cons:

- Serial up/downvoting. But this really isn't even an issue because, (1) only experienced users can vote on tag synonyms, and (2) more than one vote is required to approve a tag synonym, so the occasional serial up/downvoter won't significantly impact the overall process.

Comment: Good idea, but it'd be even better if you only got the insta-vote arrows for tags you have the points to vote on in the first place.

Comment: True... but you get the general idea of it. I just wanted to give a general description of what I think we should be doing... I'm not a web designer by any means. :)

Comment: We have long-term plans to rework the tag synonym UI, but I'll bring this up for discussion to see if it'd be a quick improvement to implement in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

This feature has been added in the [Tag synonym dashboard 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329687/295232); on the Pending approval tab, you can now vote for/against synonyms.

> [image: Tag synonym dashboard with thumbs up/down voting buttons]