# Synonyms requirement: Appears more times

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow tag synonyms where the source has more instances than the target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target)

I just had this one: Wanted to add a synonym for `stl` that points to `standard-library`. Most people, when tagging `stl` have questions about `std::vector`, `std::list` and friends, that were originally part of the "STL" but are now part of the C++ Standard Library. But the `stl` tag is more frequently used than `standard-library`, yet it makes no sense to have the mapping the other way around.

What is the reason to have that restriction on "appears more times"?

Comment: Check out the reasoning provided by waffles' answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target. The essence is that we give popularity priority, and if you want to go against that then discussion on Meta is necessary.

Comment: @Grace i see now.

Comment: FYI: You can still post a request on Meta to get the synonyms reversed.