# Merge the "cocos2d" and the "cocos2d-iphone" tags; make the first a synonym of the second

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

**TL;DR:** Make [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) a synonym of [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone), and merge the two tags.

I was asked if I'm sure that the generic [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) tag has no utility. I say yes:

- The Cocos2D engines only share the same name and general design philosophy, but are implemented by different developers with different languages. I have yet to see a question that wasn't specific to one particular Cocos2D version.
- The generic [cocos2d] tag currently only causes confusion because it discourages the use of the more appropriate, language-specific cocos2d tags [cocos2d-iphone], [cocos2d-android], [cocos2d-x], [cocos2d-python]. I'm hopeful that more users of the lesser known cocos2d engines will participate more if their questions are more easily distinguishable.

**Rationale:**
There are several variants of the Cocos2D game engine: cocos2d (for Desktops, written in Python), cocos2d-iphone (for iOS & Mac, written in ObjC), cocos2d-android (for Android, written in Java), cocos2d-x (for various mobile devices, written in C++) and many more. But other than sharing the same name, and general design principles, they have little in common and are being developed independently with different languages and SDKs as basis. In other words there is no overarching "THE cocos2d" game engine.

Due to the popularity of the cocos2d-iphone engine a lot of developers have come to think of "cocos2d" as referring solely to the cocos2d-iphone version. This is reflected by just 4 Stack Overflow questions about the Python version, whose name is in fact just "cocos2d". I've recently re-tagged those with [cocos2d-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-python). At least 90% of the "cocos2d" questions actually refer to the cocos2d-iphone engine.

**The question I asked myself is this:** should the cocos2d-iphone tag be a synonym for the more generic cocos2d tag, or should the cocos2d tag be a synonym for the cocos2d-iphone tag?

Personally I would rather have all "cocos2d tags" converted to the "cocos2d-iphone" tag, for the simple reason "cocos2d" in itself is ambiguous. It could mean any cocos2d game engine version. I believe it is because of this ambiguity that about every 7th question is tagged with both cocos2d and cocos2d-iphone tags. The cocos2d tag should in an ideal world be exclusive to the Python version, but since that cocos2d version is all but insignificant I created the cocos2d-python tag instead.

**Thus my request is this:** Delete the request for cocos2d-iphone being a synonym for cocos2d. Instead change the cocos2d tag to be a synonym for cocos2d-iphone.

**Rationale:** As it is now, the cocos2d-iphone questions are basically split in half between two tags, while other cocos2d engine version users can't be sure if they shouldn't also add the cocos2d tag. This is confusing.

I have already gone over the cocos2d tagged questions and sorted out any questions that were related to cocos2d-android, cocos2d-x, and others and tagged them accordingly to corresponding cocos2d-xxxx tags.

Here are some stats that may be helpful:

- tag: [cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d) 1792 questions, 327 followers
- tag: [cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) 1366 questions, 366 followers
- tag: [cocos2d + cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone+cocos2d) 419 questions
- tag: [cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) 13 questions, 5 followers
- tag: [cocos2d-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-android) 31 questions, 2 followers
- tag: [cocos2d-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocos2d-python) 4 questions, 1 follower

As you can see, only the cocos2d-iphone version has any relevance as of today, but this is subject to change in the future.

Comment: If you want to help with this retagging effort, please downvote this synonym suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d/synonyms
Then I'll suggest cocos2d being a synonym of cocos2d-iphone here and you can then vote on that: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d-iphone/synonyms

Comment: Doesn't the system automatically select the more-used tag in any new synonym pair as the master?

Comment: I doubt that, otherwise it wouldn't make sense why I can't suggest cocos2d as a synonym of cocos2d-iphone because the opposite has already been suggested.

Comment: Everyone, please vote on this tag synonym: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocos2d-iphone/synonyms
[cocos2d-iphone] <-- [cocos2d]

Comment: Ah, I was probably thinking of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target).