# How to request fixes in tag descriptions?

Tags: support, tags

How do I request improvements in tag descriptions?

Specifically, the `cocos2d` tag description has a blatant mistake:

> Cocos2D is a Python based open source framework for building 2D games
>   and graphical applications for Windows, Mac and Linux desktop
>   computers. Cocos2D is published under a BSD license

I would say cocos2d is not Python based at all (unless I'm missing something). If I am not mistaken, cocos2d started off purely as an Objective-C framework. These days they favor engine  cross-plataformness by using some other languages like C++ in cocos2d-x, or Lua/Javascript for scripting in many of the cocos2d *subprojects*.

Also, marginally related: How can I request tag renames and/or tag merges?

**EDIT**: Oh, I realized that maybe cocos2d did actually start as a [Python engine](http://cocos2d.org/). However, I still think that giving prominence to that in the tag is suboptimal (as cocos2d really took off thanks to the Objective-C version). I support what they are requesting on this question: [Merge the "cocos2d" and the "cocos2d-iphone" tags; make the first a synonym of the second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110650/merge-the-cocos2d-and-the-cocos2d-iphone-tags-make-the-first-a-synonym-of-t).

Comment: For your "marginally related" query, see [meta-tag:retag-request].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I request improvements in tag descriptions?

You don't *request* them, you *make* them. There's no official tag description writer, nor even a committee. [Like everything else on the website](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), tag wikis are collaboratively edit by the community. That way, people who are experts on the subject are the ones writing the material.

There are two ways to edit tag wikis:

1. Users with over 20,000 reputation, [can edit tag wikis directly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), without requiring approval. These are "trusted users", we assume they know what they're doing.
2. Everyone else can [*suggest* edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) to tag wikis, just like users with [less than 2k reputation suggest edits to questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Your suggested edits are placed into that same queue, and need to be approved by two or three other community members with [at least 5k reputation, who have earned the right to approve tag wiki edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

Either way, this process is initiated directly from the tag info page, by clicking the "Edit Tag Wiki" button.

Oh, and did I forget to mention that you can [earn badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for helping to contribute/improve tag wikis? Not only do tag wiki edits contribute toward your quota for the standard editor badges, but there are two specialized badges, just for tag wikis:

- [Tag Editor] is a bronze badge awarded for your first tag wiki edit
- [Research Assistant] is a silver badge awarded after you've edited 50 tag wikis

Comment: Oh, I just found out how to access the main tag description page, where I can see the edit button. Thanks! Before I was trying to edit them in the tag description hoover overlay itself. Maybe adding a link from the tag hoover overlay to its main page could be a good idea.

Comment: @rsanchez There sort of is one. Clicking on the tag itself takes you to the list of questions with that tag. Clicking the "info" link takes you to the tag info/wiki page. Granted, the link text is microscopic, but it's just a small popup!

Answer (score 2):

You could always go to the tag wiki page for [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) and edit the tag wiki and from there the edit can be approved.

[image]