# What happens to the old tag when a tag synonym is approved?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I saw a tag on Stack Overflow that was still in use when it really shouldn't be used anymore.  [xlinq](/questions/tagged/xlinq) was the former name of the technology, [linq-to-xml](/questions/tagged/linq-to-xml) back when it was still in development.  So I suggested [synonymizing it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq-to-xml/synonyms).

But I don't know what would happen if it did get approved.  I assumed that questions using the old tag would retain it until they were retagged manually or a mod does some magic.  So I preemptively went through the 39 questions that used the tag and changed it to use the other myself just in case.

Did I really need to do that?  Or does the approval of the synonym automatically change them all?

<sub>[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58023/how-does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-feature-work) only describes the voting process (and all other posts that I could dig up).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a synonym doesn't change any existing tags. Mods have the ability to merge tags such that all posts tagged [xlinq](/questions/tagged/xlinq) would be siliently changed to [linq-to-xml](/questions/tagged/linq-to-xml), so that's usually preferrable if there are a lot of posts; editing them manually is slow and bumps 39 posts to the front page

Comment: Don't forget the [retag-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+-status-declined+-status-completed)...

Comment: Ok so it doesn't do it automatically, got it.  39 wasn't too bad though, I'd be more concerned if it was a lot more and its use was somewhat ambiguous (fortunately there was only one use of `xlinq`).