# Include synonyms in tag suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The new tagging method is really annoying. I understand the need for assigning the proper tags on similar questions, but this means that I should already know the *standard* tags SO.

For example, I just tried to add the tag `regular-expressions` to a question and I realized that there was no such tag on SO. I had to stop and think about what other tags would be appropriate and I found `regex`. My complaint is that I shouldn't have had to think about this and SO should have recommended me other tags (including `regex`) based on other people's attempts to create new tags.

This can be implemented by monitoring re-tags and finding tags that have been added to questions which had their tags deleted. I'm sure you will notice an outlining pattern. It's worth giving it a shot as it will help people to tag their questions properly and, based on their choices, the algorithm can *learn* to be even more precise.

Answer (score 6):

This is completed *even betterer* as part of [the fancy new tag autocompleter](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/). Note that as you type, synonym matches are shown at the bottom as well, with the parent tag at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, if you do try to use `[regular-expressions]`, it will be automatically retagged to `[regex]`.

As for your suggestion itself, I believe it's been suggested here before, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It would be nice if this was documented.

Comment: @Tom See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) for more info on tag synonyms. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms for the master list.