# What does (s) mean in the tag preview?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-autocomplete

When I add a tag, Stack Overflow will suggest some tags. Those tags have numbers next to them. Sometimes, instead of a number, there is the letter 's'. The tag doesn't show up in the question after editing.

What does 's' mean and why doesn't it show the tag?

Comment: There is a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63304/54262) to change that (s) to something else.

Comment: Yeah, this one got me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that tag is a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and will be automatically and silently renamed to another tag when you submit.

Find the [tag's page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/example/synonyms) to see what the "master" synonym is.