# (s) next to tag?

Tags: support, tags

Hello,

I was asking a question and was tagging it when I saw an `s` next to a particular tag. Normally it shows the number of questions associated with that tag.

So instead of:

```
tag (12)
```

Or some number, I saw the letter `S`, like so:

```
tag (s)
```

What does it mean? That the tag is `soft-deleted`?

Comment: you may be interested in supporting [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63304/improve-display-of-tag-synonyms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag is a [tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) for a master tag.