# Change [osx] to [mac-os-x]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I suggest that the tag [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) is changed to [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x).

The problem is now that many questions are about **Mac OS X** but when the author starts writing the tags with **mac** there is only a tag [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) but the [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) tag would be more appropriate in most cases for developers on StackOverflow, and there is no [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) tag suggested since the [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) tag starts on `os` and not on `mac`.

Take a look at the [latest questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac?sort=newest&pagesize=30) that are tagged [mac](/questions/tagged/mac):

- A few are offtopic and should be migrated to SuperUser.com
- A few are tagged both [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) and [mac](/questions/tagged/mac)
- Most of the questions are tagged [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) but are about **Mac OS X** ([osx](/questions/tagged/osx))

At the moment [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) is a synonym to [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) but it would be better if [mac-os-x](/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) was the "visible name".

Comment: It seems more like `[mac-os-x]` should show up in the suggestion list for `mac-` -- why are synonyms excluded?

Comment: @Michael: That would be good, I wrote a comment on [Include synonyms in tag suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/include-synonyms-in-tag-suggestions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what exactly *is* the difference between [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) and [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) ?

I don't get it.

(the new tag completer largely solves your original request, but can any Apple users explain what the distinction would be between a question tagged [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) and one that is instead tagged [osx](/questions/tagged/osx)? It's not like I can buy a mac that is running any other operating system...)

edit: complete, tags are merged -- I see no reason [mac](/questions/tagged/mac) needs to exist at all, so it was merged into [osx](/questions/tagged/osx).

Comment: I think [mac] is used for the actual hardware (opposite to e.g. [pc]) while [osx] is used for the operating system and [mac-os-x] (opposite to e.g. [windows] and [linux]). I think that most questions on StackOverflow is about [osx] (the OS environment) while on SuperUser both [mac] and [osx] is used. The think that annoys me most, is that all mac-os-x related questions are split up on multiple tags.

Comment: SuperUser has a clear tag-wiki for [mac]: `Questions that relate to the actual hardware of Macintosh, a brand of computers created and sold by Apple Inc. Includes the iMac, Mac mini, Mac Pro, MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, and MacBook. Not to be confused with MAC address.`

Comment: While the SU tag-wiki for [osx] is: `A series of Unix-based operating systems and graphical user interfaces developed, marketed, and sold by Apple Inc.`

Comment: And, yes, a new tag completer will also solve my request.

Comment: I’ve noticed that the mac tag is still being used. Is there any option to prevent users from using it, or automatically replace it with the osx tag?

Comment: @bav thanks for the reminder, I went ahead and synonymized it then